# how do i change my makefile for debug build?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, makefile, eclipse-cdt

i have the attached makefile code that build my project in linux ubuntu 10.04 using arm-linux-gcc compiler:

```
CROSS_COMPILE =

LIBDIR      = ./lib

LIBFCGI     = $(LIBDIR)/libfcgi.a
LIBOS       = $(LIBDIR)/libos.a
LIBSCPI     = $(LIBDIR)/libscpi.a
STATIC_LIBS = $(LIBFCGI) $(LIBOS) $(LIBSCPI)

COPTIONS = -g -Wall
CINCDIRS = -I./include
USEROPTS = 
CFLAGS = $(COPTIONS) $(CINCDIRS) $(USEROPTS)
LDFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -lpthread 

CC  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)-gcc

ifeq ($(CC),arm-linux-gcc)
STATIC_LIBS += $(LIBDIR)/libm.a
STATIC_LIBS += $(LIBDIR)/libc.so.0
endif

fcgi_responder = fcgi-responder
fcgi_responder_OBJS = fcgi-responder.o

TARGET =  $(fcgi_responder)

LINKLIBS    = -L$(LIBDIR) -lfcgi -los -lscpi -lm

all: $(TARGET)

fcgi-responder: $(fcgi_responder_OBJS) $(STATIC_LIBS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< $(LINKLIBS) -o $@

.c.o: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    -rm -f *.o *.a *~ fcgi-responder
```

i am trying to remote debug using eclipse cdt,
i don't know how to change it in order to get debug build  (usually i don't work with makefiles)
after several settings i can build the project in the eclipse using this makefile as release build
please advice
itai

please advice

Comment: Do you mean ``-g`` flag?

Comment: `COPTIONS = -g -Wall` u have this entry in your makefile... what specific flags do u intend to compile with for a debug build...

Answer (score 0):

The line that sets COPTIONS includes the -g flag, which enables debug data.  It doesn't appear there is anything for you to do to the Makefile; the problem lie elsewhere.